# Calculate median on pre-aggregated data (having means and counts) in R rstats

Tags: r, statistics, aggregation, median

How can I get a proper `median` calculation on data that has been already aggregated?

For example, if I have a data frame that looks like  this:

```
> df <- data.frame(name = c("A","B","C","D"), count = c(1,3,5,2), avg = c(100,50,20,10))
> df
# A tibble: 4 × 3
   name count   avg
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     A     1   100
2     B     3    50
3     C     5    20
4     D     2    10
```

Assume we don't know much what's inside the bins, but assume there is little variation within bins.
To the best of our knowledge, we would line up the values like this:

```
10 10 20 20 20 20 20 50 50 50 100
```

Out of 11 values, a median would be the **6th** one, which is **20**

But if I simply take the `median()`, R takes it over 4 values: `10, 20, 50, 100`

```
> median(df$avg)
[1] 35
```

Which is not what I want.

How can I go around this and "unfold" the data set?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was solved as commented by Zheyuan Li.
It is simple, and I'm surprised I didn't know about it.

```
with(df, median(rep.int(avg, count)) )
```

Comment: If you have a dataset where the counts are very high, this will be inefficient, so instead you can first divide all the counts by some power of 10 and round off to the nearest whole number to produce a much smaller dataset with approximately the same proportions.

Comment: You can do this was any vectors. For example `median(rep(df$avg, df$count))`. I also didn't realise "rep" was vectorised though, very nice.