# Transform counts of individuals with an age into median and IQR

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with age data for the number of customers who access an app in a given year. The first column is the age value in years c(0, 1, 2...) the next columns are the individual years. The row value for the year columns are the number of individuals who have that age value who accessed the app that calendar year.

I want to calculate the median (IQR) age for usage during a calender year. Can anyone help?

I created a weighted average of each age row and added the column. That only provides the mean.

Sample data:

```r
structure(list(
  `Row Labels` = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
  b_21 = c(35, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4), 
  b_22 = c(79, 68, 87, 66, 44, 36),
  q_21 = c(56, 34, 27, 10, 12, 10), 
  q_22 = c(71, 64, 45, 25, 27, 16), 
  wc_21 = c(1226, 159, 98, 56, 48, 39), 
  wc_22 = c(1127, 120, 73, 66, 38, 32), 
  total = c(2594, 450, 335, 227, 172, 137)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Row Labels = the value of the age, each year 21, 22 etc contains the n for each age.

Comment: What are `b`, `q`, and `wc`? Which one is the count?

Answer (score 1):

Building on a comment from @GregorThomas, you can compute quantiles from counts by finding where the cumulative count is >= a given percentage of the total. Which you can then use to get medians and IQRs.

```r
quantile_counts <- function(x, n, probs) {
  n <- n[order(x)]
  x <- sort(x)
  # find ranks corresponding to each prob
  ranks <- probs * (sum(n) - 1) + 1
  n_cum <- cumsum(n)
  sapply(ranks, \(rank) {
    pos <- which.max(n_cum >= rank)
    pos_f <- which.max(n_cum >= floor(rank))
    # test for fractional rank
    if (pos == pos_f) {
      x[[pos]]
    } else {
      x[[pos_f]] + diff(x[c(pos_f, pos)]) * rank %% 1
    }
  })
}

# median = 50th %ile
median_counts <- function(x, n) quantile_counts(x, n, probs = 0.5)

# IQR = difference btw 25th and 75th %ile
IQR_counts <- function(x, n) {
  diff(quantile_counts(x, n, probs = c(0.25, 0.75)))
}
```

It’s not clear in your sample data which columns contain the counts — I used `b_21` and `b_22`.

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  rename(age = `Row Labels`) %>%
  summarize(across(
    b_21:b_22, 
    list(
      median = \(x) median_counts(age, x), 
      IQR = \(x) IQR_counts(age, x)
    )
  ))

# # A tibble: 1 × 4
#   b_21_median b_21_IQR b_22_median b_22_IQR
#         <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1           0        2           2        2
```

Note:

- This uses linear interpolation for fractional ranks, corresponding to the default `type = 7` in `stats::quantile()`.
- Because this uses `floor(x) == x` and modulo (`%%`), a more robust implementation would include safeguards for floating point errors. See the source for `stats:::quantile.default` for some possible approaches.
- See [this alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41048070/17303805) by @ZheyuanLi (again pointed out by @GregorThomas), which is simpler but may be less efficient in large datasets.

Comment: I will advice against uncount. Suppose, you have a factor of 1m multiplied to the `n` above, this will take ages to solve. I recommend using the formula of weighted mean/quantile

Comment: In sample data with 1.2M rows, execution time is < 1s. I’m not aware of a formula for deriving median from counts (as opposed to weighted mean), but would be curious if you know of one.

Comment: To find the median from (sorted) counts, you need to find the first row where the cumulative sum is greater than or equal to half the grand sum. `which.max(cumsum(n) >= sum(n) / 2)` should work.

Comment: @GregorThomas makes perfect sense, thank you! You could add logic to handle cases where the median falls between two values, and adapt the same method to 25th and 75th %ile for IQR. Do you plan to post an answer? Otherwise I may work this up into another answer.

Comment: No plan to post, feel free to use the idea. You might want to poke around a bit, I'd be surprised if there isn't a nice robust implementation of this in some popular package.

Comment: ...though upon my own poking around I see mostly [answers like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41048070/903061), which are essentially the same as yours with `uncount()` (though probably more efficient if they operate only on a couple columns, not the whole data frame).